# How perform task in airflow that executes regardless of failed tasks but fail the DAG when error appeared in previous tasks?

Tags: python, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

The scenario is simple airflow DAG starts a cluster, submits a job and terminates cluster. The problem is that the cluster needs to be terminated always. E.g. even when previous task failed. If I add `TriggerRule.ALL_DONE` - I guarantee that cluster is terminated. But in that case DAG will be successful. If I change `TriggerRule` DAG will fail but cluster will be run.

So is there a way to tell airflow - execute task regardless DAG previous tasks failed or not and mark DAG as failed?

Comment: you can use setup/teardown to ensure cleanup of resources:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/setup-and-teardown.html#setup-and-teardown

Comment: you can also check the task status in the success/failure callbacks and raise AirflowFailException to fail the DAG.